# How do I write this mathematical expression with nested divisions in Python?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble writing this expression for the entry level certification course I'm taking.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: x = float(input("Enter value for x: "))
y = (1/1 + 1(1 / (1/1)(1 + 1))
# Write your code here.

print("y =", y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use images, instead copy and paste the code.

That question is probably for you to learn how to use parenthesis:

```py
1/(x+1/(x+1/(x + 1/x)))
```

Comment: I had to create the code but I had trouble understanding the expression. And yes, you're exactly right!!

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(x):
    return 1 /(x + 1 / (x + 1 / (x + 1.0 / x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this problem strongly suggests recursion to me. I'm not a huge fan of recursion in python, so I would probably implement this as a loop, but I suspect the question is meant for recursion.

How about we define a recursive method like:

```
def recursive_div(depth, x, y=0):
    if depth==1:
        return x + 1 / x
    return y + 1 / recursive_div(depth-1, x, x)
```

Then we can do a:

```
print(recursive_div(4, 2))
```

We can verify this with one of the other answers:

```
def foo(x):
    return 1.0 /(x + 1.0 / (x + 1.0 / (x + 1.0 / x)))

print(foo(2) == recursive_div(4, 2))
```